# which features are most important for skin diseases classification?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, deep-learning, feature-extraction

I am working on skin problem detection and am using a skin image dataset. I want to extract features from the images, but I can't understand which handcrafted features I should extract. I did some research on it. There are many features with LBP, HOG, HUE, and so on. There are numerous. Do I need to remove and concatenate those before passing it to an algorithm? I mean, if I'm exacting HOG and LBP, will I merge them both and then give them to the ML or DL algorithm?

Comment: I would not recommend random attempts. Try all detectors that you want and observe how they behave.

Comment: if I'm exacting HOG and LBP, can I merge them both and then give them to the ML or DL algorithm?

Comment: I repeat my comment.